# Why are static variables and methods in java called directly?

Tags: java, static

Why static variables are directly called without any use of object in java?Are they stored in some different memory location?And why only static methods can called with the name of the class directly without creating its object ?for example

```
class First
{
   public static void ss()
   {
     System.out.println("This genius will give answer");
   }
}

class Second
{
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
       First.ss(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: static means that belongs to the class not to an instance of that class

Comment: static members are stored in stack or in heap or some other location?

Comment: Some other location. Check the answer of rocketboy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes static resources belong to the class and not the objects. And are stored in a separate location kind of `global` location. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569557/what-is-the-actual-memory-place-for-static-variables).

Comment: static members are stored in stack or in heap or some other location?

Comment: Follow the link in the answer above.

Comment: Rocketboy your rocket reached to moon successfully..Thnx it solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

[As docs says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

> Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory.
>
> The Java programming language supports static methods as well as static variables. Static methods, which have the static modifier in their declarations, should be invoked with the class name, **without the need for creating an instance of the class**, as in

```
ClassName.methodName(args)
```