# Permgen space vs Meta space

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Metaspace introduced in JDK 8 is still part of Runtime data areas in JVM ? How does it is different from Permgen space except auto increase in Size.?

Comment: Did you try that research thing?

Answer (score 0):

Both are almost can increase same, As you pointed out Metaspace can increase dynamically, to take care of dynamically loading and unloading of classes.
[More details are available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131165/what-is-the-difference-between-permgen-and-metaspace)