# Where is the reference of metaspace area or permgen in java

Tags: java, jvm

I'm reading java language spec and jvm spec.

but I can't find the reference about PermGen or Metaspace.

As far as I know, **PermGen in java7 is changed to Metaspace in java8.

But I can't find about it in official documents like java spec.**

I'm trying to understand java's memory area right way.

In JVM 7 and 8 spec, there is only the reference about 6 runtime data area which are `PC Register`, `JVM stacks`, `Heap`, `Method Area`, `Runtime Constant Pool`, `Native Method stacks`.
So, when can I get the information from?
I appreciate you.

Comment: There is no reference in the JLS or the JVM specifications.  PermGen and Metaspace were / are implementation details of the Sun / Oracle implementation of Java.

Comment: @Stephen C Oh.. really? I didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: There is no requirement to have a PermGen or Metaspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PermGen**(Permanent generation) has been completely removed in JDK 8.

In JDK 8, classes metadata is now stored in the native heap
and this space is called **Metaspace**.

A very good information is given here : https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Regarding the differences : [What is the difference between PermGen and Metaspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131165/what-is-the-difference-between-permgen-and-metaspace)

Oracle Blog reference : https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/about-g1-garbage-collector,-permanent-generation-and-metaspace