# When are static fields initialized?

Tags: java, android

When are static fields initialized? If I never instantiate a class, but I access a static field, are ALL the static blocks and private static methods used to instantiate private static fields called (in order) at that instant? or when app is started?

Comment: For java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/when-does-static-class-initialization-happen. We can assume it may be similar

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java to develop your android applications the static fields are initialized when the app start and they are stored in the heap memory.
If you want to access a static field you don't need an instance of a class you can access it using your class name ClassName.staticField example:

```
Person.staticAge
```

If you need more information, refer to this

[static allocation in java - heap, stack and permanent generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849634/static-allocation-in-java-heap-stack-and-permanent-generation/3849819#3849819)