# Are variables stored on the stack or heap with their perspective value in Java?

Tags: java

So in Java I know that primitive values will be on the stack and that reference values for objects will be stored on the heap. Now will the variable, which is used as a storage location in memory, also be in the stack with that associated primitive value or be on the heap with the associated reference type value?

Comment: Why not read for yourself: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6

Comment: @Michael which particular section are you referring to on that link, sorry?

Comment: I used anchor ref for the section, 2.6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [static allocation in java - heap, stack and permanent generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849634/static-allocation-in-java-heap-stack-and-permanent-generation)